# ¿Por qué mi FloatingActionButton no queda en la parte de abajo de la activity?

Tags: android

Tengo este Layout,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.ruben.red4.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Pero el FloatingActionButton queda arriba a la derecha y yo esperaba que quede abajo a la derecha. ¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 3):

Lo que necesitas en tu layout es usar un RelativeLayout en lugar de LinearLayout y agregar las propiedades :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Así sería tu layout:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.ruben.red4.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a la sombra cuadrada es un detalle conocido que se muestra en algunas    **[versiones del OS Android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175067)**

la solución que comentas :

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

no funcionaría, te sugiero cambiar en tu `build.gradle` a tener mimimo la versión 22.2.1 de la librería de diseño:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No se esta ubicando donde esperas por que estas utilizando un `LinearLayout`, el cual apila los elementos de acuerdo a su orden de aparición en el XML.

Para poder darle una ubicación relativa a la pantalla, debes usar un `RelativeLayout`.

Si realmente necesitas utilizar el `LinearLayout` para organizar otros elementos, puedes agregarlo dentro del `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout .. 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- aqui puedes poner el LinearLayout de ser necesario -->

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id=...
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Si quieres cierto espaciado entre el botón y el borde de la pantalla, utiliza los margenes para resolverlo.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, ya me lo pone abajo, lo he metido directamente dentro de un RelativeLayout.

Otra cosa, el Floating button sale con la sombra de un cuadrado. Creo que es porque le falta la propiedad:

app:borderWidth="0dp"

Pero el app no lo reconoce, por lo tanto son dos las dudas que me surgen ahora:

    ¿Cómo quitar ese color blanco al trozo que no ocupa el botón redonde y que conforman el cuadrado?
    y por qué no reconoce el app.

Un saludo y de nuevo gracias.

Comment: @Red en que version de android lo estas probando? por cierto recuerda marcar la respuesta (esta o cualquier otra) como correcta si te ha solucionado el problema para que otros miembros y futuros lectores sepan que lo solucionaste, es una marca en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta.